# ASP.NET Data binding not working properly OnSelectedItemChanged event

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

Hi :) I'm making a simple form. The user is prompted to fill in street addresses. Every user is allowed to add up to 5 street addresses. Therefore, I have 5 one and the same controls. I am using a database to provide lists of all countries and cities. I am listening to the OnSelectedItemChanged event on every Country list. When this event is triggered, I am connecting to the database and binding the corresponding City list to the appropriate Country ID.

So, it is fairly simple. I could do 5 different event handlers, but I wanted to create just one event handler and listen to it for every single Country list item.

My Country lists are called lstContactCountry1, lstContactCountry2, ... up to number 5, and the City lists are called lstContactCity1, lstContactCity2 respectively.

I am using DropDownLists.

So, my problem is that when I change the selected item of whichever Country dropdown, except for number 1, the City list has not databinded at all. Databinding works only after I have changed the selected item of the first country list once. Furthermore, even if I have changed the selected item of the first country list once and then, change, for example, the selected item of the second country list the City lists of both of them have binded to the same country, even if they shouldn't.

ASP.NET code-behind:

```
protected void lstContactCountry1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // lstContactCountry is the sender of the event
        DropDownList lstContactCountry = sender as DropDownList;

        // Get the number of DropDownList
        char lstNumber = lstContactCountry.ID[lstContactCountry.ID.Length - 1];
        lblTemp.Text = "Sender: " + lstContactCountry.ID;

        // Get the IdCountry property from the selected value of the DropDownList
        string idCountry = lstContactCountry1.SelectedValue;

        // Some ADO.NET code :)
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT IdCity, CityName FROM City WHERE IdCountry = '" + idCountry + "' ORDER BY CityName", connection);

        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "City");

        // lstContactCity is the City DropDownList below the selected Country DropDownList
        DropDownList lstContactCity = this.Master.FindControl("phSecuredPageMainContent").FindControl("lstContactCity" + lstNumber.ToString()) as DropDownList;
        lblTemp.Text += "<br />Receiver: ";

        lstContactCity.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["City"];
        lstContactCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
        lstContactCity.DataValueField = "IdCity";

        this.DataBind();

        // Adding a default value to the list
        lstContactCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("City", "0"));
        lstContactCity.SelectedIndex = 0;           
    }
```

EDIT:
I found the mistake. It is on this line of code:

```
        string idCountry = lstContactCountry1.SelectedValue;
```

I've unintentionally added a "1" at the end of the control's name. That's all. :)

Comment: [Sql injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `this.DataBind();`, which databinds everything on the page that has been bound (datasource set in code behind or a <%# used in aspx code).

You should start fixing this by calling databind on the actual controls that you are binding.

```
lstContactCity.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I changed the code the way you told me but it is still not working :(

Comment: I found the mistake and I wrote it at the bottom of the question's description.

By the way, you're right that this.DataBind() binds all elements that use data binding on the page, but it still worked okay (visually) with binding the whole page. So, this was definitely not the problem. By the way, I fixed this line because it really didn't make sense to bind the whole page. 

So, after all - thanks again :)